# Javascript closures on heap or stack?

Tags: javascript, closures, heap-memory, stack-memory

Where does JavaScript (according to the standard) store closures: heap or stack?
Is there a third explicit place for closures?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [very nice writeup](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-6-closures/) to find your answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the end it is an implementation detail of the runtime. [See Phoenix link](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-6-closures/)

*As to implementations, for storing local variables after the context is destroyed, the stack-based implementation is not fit any more (because it contradicts the definition of stack-based structure). Therefore in this case closured data of the parent context are saved in the dynamic memory allocation (in the “heap”, i.e. heap-based implementations), with using a garbage collector (GC) and references counting. Such systems are less effective by speed than stack-based systems. However, implementations may always optimize it: at parsing stage to find out, whether free variables are used in function, and depending on this decide — to place the data in the stack or in the “heap”.*

Comment: Phoenix link doesn't work. Can you provide some information about it please? Or maybe another valid link if it was moved to another place @Phoenix

Comment: You can still read the complete article here: https://web.archive.org/web/20220228071504/https://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-6-closures/

Comment: but the variable used in closure could a local variable of a parent function and thus stored on stack (with no reference to heap if non-primitive), when that parent execution context popped of from stack, its variable environment containing that local variable is also removed from stack, then how closure function stores reference to it ? does before removing parent fn exec. context, that local variable is copied to heap ??

Comment: A copy to the heap might do the trick or variables known to be in closures would be created on the heap in the first place. This is likely a good area for optimizations and "smart trickery".